# Drawing Ellipsoid using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am currently struggle with how to draw an ellipsoid with the equation of 9x^2+y^2+z^2=9

currently i drawed one with the command

`[x, y, z] = ellipsoid(0,0,0,1/9,1,1)`

but i am not sure if it is correct or not

is there anyway to double check it?

Comment: Did you read the help? Is your ellipse in the standard form for ellipsoid? (Hint, it is not. But XR, YR and ZR are not as you have provided.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on that hint: First off, you are putting in radius squared, not radius as needed.  (You did figure out that you needed an inverse, though, so that's good.)  Second, you FIRST have to divide everything by 9, because the standard form has 1 on the RHS.

```
9x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9
divide by 9 =>
x^2 + (y^2)/9 + (z^2)/9 = 1
x^2 + (y/3)^2 + (z/3)^2 = 1
```

Your radii are 1, 3, and 3.

Lastly, you can use surf(x,y,z) to plot the output of ellipsoid.

Really, you need to read the help file: help ellipsoid